# Creating App Store Distribution Certificate - What to enter in Common Name field?

Tags: iphone, certificate, app-store, portal

When creating the app store distribution certificate in the certificate assistant, do I enter my name in the Common Name field, or the company name?

[This page](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/distribution/index.action) says, "In the Common Name field enter your Company/Organization/Department name" while the add certificate area of the portal it says "In the Common Name field, enter your name"

Answer (score 2):

It needs to match the common name in the distribution certificate the Apple developer site gave you. If you use the keychain access utility you can go look at the certificate to see what that is.

(if you look in your dev configuration, you'll see the same field matches the common name of your developer certificate, which is a different certificate. You'll find that certificate in the keychain too)

Answer (score 0):

I used the Company / Organization field of my developer connection profile, and they seem to have accepted the app for review.  I guess that works then.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the name displayed under "Team" > "Contact Info" tab of the Program Portal where you are submitting your certificate signing request to. It should be the company name if you are a team agent of a corporate account, or your personal name if you have a personal account.